# jquery scripts not working after sending POST request with php on itself

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page generated using php, and after i send a post request from page on itself javascript stop working. How can i fix it? I need to change my page content using php.
My script looks like:

```
$(function(){
 my code here...
});
```

And i'm sending request with this function:

```
function sendPostRequest(params){
       var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)document.body.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;};
       xmlhttp.open("POST","catalog_main.php",false);
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       document.body.innerHTML="";
       xmlhttp.send(params);
     }
```

Comment: maybe you have problem in JS file ,bcoz if your js has logical error ,then next code will not execute

Comment: it works before i send a request, so there is no logical error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you say "javascript stops working" you mean that events which have a javscript function tied to them are not firing that function.

I think the root of the problem is:

```
document.body.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText
```

If you bind a function to an event at page load then you are binding it to the event on a specific element.  When you run the above you remove all elements in the page body and replace them with new ones.  The new ones may have the same class/id but they are new elements which do not have any events bound.

There are two solutions: either  encapsulate all your event binding in a function, which you run both on page load and after replaceing the page as above or use only delegated events where all events are techically bound to the body element itself.

**Edit:**
I see the questions is tagged jQuery (I wonder why ypou are not using $.ajax in this case?).  Using jQuery you can do the delegated events as such:  Instead of

```
$(function(){
   $('#foo').click(function(){
      alert('Foo clicked');
   });
   $('.bar').change(function(){
      //do something
   });
});
```

You can use

```
$(function(){
   $('body')
   .on('click', '#foo', function(){
      alert('Foo clicked');
   })
   .on('change', '.bar', function(){
      //do something
   });
});
```

For more info see the [jQuery docs on .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**Second Edit**

To use the first option (9encapsulate all events in a function) then, based on the same events as the above example, change the document ready to the following:

```
function set_events(){
   $('#foo').click(function(){
      alert('Foo clicked');
   });
   $('.bar').change(function(){
      //do something
   });
}
$(function(){
   set_events();
});
```

Then change you ajax response habndler to 
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

```
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
     document.body.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     set_events();
  }
```

};

Comment: OK, can you explain in detail how can i apply a first solution? A simple example please)) Which event fires after replaceing the page, how can i track it?

Comment: You do it yourself when you replace the page.  See my second edit.  Personally, I would use the delegated version I think.

Answer (score -1):

You can send Request with this function and don't forget to add you jquery file

```
      function sendRequest(param1,param2)
      {
          $.post('index.php',{ 'name': param1,'password':param2}, function(data)
           {
             if(data) 
             {
               alert('success');
             }
           });
      }
```